# passing function as arguments in python

Tags: python

I am trying to get my head around this one.

So here is what I want to do:
I have three functions.
say, foo,bar and foo_bar

```
def foo_bar(function):
   for i in range(20):
      function # execute function
def foo(someargs):
   print "hello from foo"

def bar(someargs):
   print " hello from bar"
```

and when i do `foo_bar(foo)` `# how to specify arguments to foo??`

I am expecting that I see `"hello from foo" 20 times`?

But since I am not seeing that.. I clearly dont understand this well enough?

Answer (score 5):

You're not calling the function. You call a function called `function` by following the name `function` with brackets `()`, and inside those brackets you put any arguments you need:

```
function(function)
```

I've passed function as a parameter to itself because your `foo` and `bar` take arguments, but do nothing with them.

Answer (score 2):

This should do basically what you want:

```
def foo_bar(function):
   for i in range(20):
      function(i) # execute function
def foo(someargs):
   print "hello from foo"

def bar(someargs):
   print " hello from bar"

foo_bar(foo)
foo_bar(bar)
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs have a section on this [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists). You most likely want to construct `foo_bar` as

```
def foo_bar(function, *func_args):
    for i in range(20):
        function(func_args)

def foo(a):
    print "hello %s"%a
```

You can then call it as

```
foo_bar(foo, 'from foo!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make foo_bar return a function that accept the parameters to pass to the internal function:

```
def foo_bar(fn, n=20):
    def _inner(*args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(n):
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return _inner
```

and call it like:

```
foo_bar(foo)('some_param')
```